# Rewriting a URL with a query string fails

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have read a number of posts here as well as Googling for a couple of hours and have been trying to get the following working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options All
    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteRule ^content/tagged/(\w+)/?$ /content.html?tagged=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have confirmed mod_rewrite is installed and I have made sure Allow Override is properly set. (Apache has been restarted!)

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`http://example.com/content/tagged/science` should support the rewrite of `http://example.com/content.html?tagged=science`, but fails totally.

This rewrite should be pretty simple, unless I have done something boneheaded. Have I done something boneheaded?

**EDIT:** I have also tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^content/tagged/([a-z]+)/?$ /content.html?tagged=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off `MultiViews` since source URL starts with `/content` and there is a matching `content.html` file. Also makes sure to start target URL without `/` to forward request to current directory's `content.html` file.

```
Options All -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^content/tagged/(\w+)/?$ content.html?tagged=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Flags used are:

```
NC  - Ignore case
QSA - Query String Append
L   - Last Rule
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Do you have some special plugin that says when there is a post with the tag? how do you get here so fast?

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. I added `-MultiViews` as you have shown and it still is not working.

Comment: @PanamaJack: lol :) no there is no plugin. Also I am not that fast, have seen faster responses in Java and regex tags.

Comment: Yep - 500 error received. Literally added 'garbage' to the top of the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122926/discussion-between-anubhava-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: That leading slash was something I was wondering/questioning about myself earlier, going back to the root like that.